# Is Stack Overflow merging two different accounts by email without the user's consent?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, privacy

I had one account through Google with email X and another account through myopenid.com. I happened to add the same email X to this myopenid.com account. My intention was to stop using the Google account in favor of the new myopenid.com account.

After some time asking and answering questions with my openid.com account **I am astonished to find out that it is now merged into my Google account**. That creates all kinds of privacy issues. I thought the email on my Stack Overflow account was private. Did I miss anything here?

To be clear, I wanted to preserve my privacy in the second account, but now since all my recent questions were transferred to the old account, my privacy is completely lost.

And it looks like there is no verification for the email field in my profile, so if Stack Overflow is using that info to merge, there is a very serious security bug. If it is merging based on something else, that's even worse. *I think your account belongs to that user here. Let me merge it.* Terrible!

Comment: Merging will usually take place when there is abuse between the two accounts (eg. cross-voting). Did you do anything like that?

Comment: If you wanted to switch from a Google account to an open ID account, why wouldn't you want to take your questions/answers with you?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - As a side note, we don't do this anymore. Accounts are only merged on user request by the community staff or in automatic associations, like what happened here.

Comment: @BradLarson It has happened to me very recently. It is my opinion that this is very bad as it hurts privacy badly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't remember having verified those emails. I wonder what happens if I put your email address in my account, if my questions go to your account.

Comment: So, openid.com let you add an email address without needing to log in and without needing to verify it?

Comment: @J. Steen I think he's referring to the E-Mail address in your profile field. I was just able to change mine without any confirmation. I don't completely see through the process right now but that would obviously be a problem

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well, he added the email from the first account to the second one (using openid) last, so I was assuming he was talking about that. Isn't it the *login* email that matters, anyway?

Comment: Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism, or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.

Answer (score 27):

This happens automatically. The process you followed is actually [the one we recommend to folks who want to merge their accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) - you only need to contact us and give consent if you can't make the automated process work for some reason.

**Having multiple accounts is not explicitly supported by the system** (it's not *forbidden*, but you can't depend on it working either - particularly if your accounts interact in any way at all). Your email and credentials are private in that we don't share them with 3rd parties (see: [Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)), but they're most definitely used to associate accounts; that's... kinda their primary purpose!

Comment: Did I miss something here? Both of these accounts are *yours*, right?

Comment: @Astonished How would two different peoples accounts ever get merged? Your accounts used the same email address. That would impossible in any other scenario as the creating an account/changing and email address does not take affect until the link has been clicked within the cofirm email.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not illegal to have two different accounts on stack overflow. I used the same email on them and now they are merged behind my back. You used private info to merge two account that were not supposed to  be together.

Comment: @Astonished - I'm really wondering *why* it matters so much to you... was there a reason you needed two accounts? Seems like it's just more work for the DBAs.

Comment: @Mike You are asking me what was the reason that I needed privacy. If I put your email address here on my profile and suddenly my questions appears as they were yours how would you feel? The accounts were separate and independent. And now they were merged together without my consent. That's definitely not cool if not illegal.

Comment: @Astonished You couldn't use this to transfer your questions to another user. This only happens for logins with verified email addresses.

Comment: @Astonished the email address on your profile is yours alone. No one can see it besides you and the owners of SO's databases.... so.. my email is on my profile, but you can't see it. If you give information to SO and they use it internally to manage databases and fix (what they may see as) discrepancies with accounts, how is that a breach of security? Where did you think your information was going when you typed it in?

Comment: @Mike I don't remember having verified those emails. I wonder what happens if I put your email address in my account, if my questions go to your account. But even if you verified the email, why go ahead and join two very different and independent accounts? Just because they happened to have the same email? I was naive to give the right email to stackoverflow as it was clear that I wanted to keep both accounts independent. I would never expect that such a thing would happen behind my back.

Comment: @Astonished Why did you want to have multiple accounts?

Comment: @Bart I don't seem to get a verification E-Mail when changing my address in my profile though? I just set it to an address that I've never used in a Stack Overflow context before, and the change seems to have gone through (see my Gravatar http://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka) If that E-Mail field could really lead to account mergings, that would indeed be a problem

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It wasn't for any illegal activities, that's for sure. It was for privacy issues. And it is not illegal to have two accounts on stack overflow.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Do you now have to use that new email to log in?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Facebook, Google and other trusted logins that have an associated email address implicitly verify that email address because Stack Exchange trusts that they send accurate information.

Comment: @JeremyBanksᐛ But openid.com does not verify anything. So if stackoverflow is using that info to merge, there is a very serious security bug. If it is merging based on something else, that's even worse. I think your account belongs to that user here. Let me merge it. Terrible!

Comment: @Etienne de Martel you clearly do not know much about privacy laws. If I am not doing anything illegal I am entitled to have privacy, at least in the US.

Comment: @Astonished Iff that is an accurate account then yes, I agree, that is a serious security issue. Let me see if I can reproduce.

Comment: @Astonished Your OpenID provider *did* verify the address with you. If we're talking about the OpenID associated E-Mail, then I don't think there is a problem here. I thought you were talking about the E-Mail address you can change in your profile. I don't see how this is a *legal* case either way, though, seeing as you specified the same E-Mail address both times.

Comment: @Astonished To be clear - merging accounts does not violate your privacy. It simply inconveniences you when you wish to be anonymous. But to also be clear - I understand your frustration. It's always annoying when things you don't want happen automatically.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks You can create an openid without any email. The only info that could have linked the two accounts where the email I filled on my SO profile.

Comment: If you logged into two different accounts using the same login, there's no information leak - I'm frankly *@astonished* to hear you think otherwise. If there's something else going on here, you should probably start by linking your actual account - based on your description here, this is a tempest in a teapot.

Comment: Well this escalated quickly...

Comment: @Pekka Have you ever created an OpenID.com account? They don't even ask for any email. I am talking about the email I voluntarily provided to SO through my SO profile.

Comment: @Tony Possible security issues are always important to probe and handle quickly. Even if it turns out to not be one. =)

Comment: I can't even access openid.com because lol google ads being blocked by my proxy. How's *that* for secure. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I'm assuming he's referring to myopenid.com instead.

Comment: @Astonished I was unable to reproduce this behaviour. I created a new Gmail account, and created [a Meta Stack Overflow account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/214216/test-account-with-google-login) with it. Then I created a MyOpenID account using the same email address -- but without verifying it -- and created [a Meta Stack Overflow account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/214217/test-account-with-myopenid-log) with it as well. The accounts were not merged...

Comment: (ctn'd) ...I was unable to add the email address to the profile of the second account, because it said "This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.".

Comment: @Astonished They don't do that without permission anymore (and they did it rarely in the past). I would be very surprised if you didn't cause this by logging in to both accounts using the same account, either Google or MyOpenID. This may have happened if you tried to switch from one account to another without logging out -- the flow there is rather unclear, a consequence of them "not supporting" multiple accounts.

Comment: @JeremyBanksᐛ I see. Thanks, Jeremy. It does not matter if it was done by human or machine. I think it is a bug in the system that can cause SO problems. SO should never merge two accounts without the explicit user consent. If this is a bug it is a bad one.

Comment: @Astonished: we generally merge accounts *manually* only when someone creates them accidentally (for instance, this morning someone created a new account to post an update to his own question) or when there's a terms of service violation of some sort (and that's more likely to lead to deletion rather than merging). In other words, it's done as a courtesy. I rather doubt that either happened in this case; if you don't feel like linking to your real account publicly, please use the "contact us" link at the bottom to let us know about it privately.

Comment: @Shog9 I did send you an email reporting the problem. It is not the end of the world for me. I am not going to get a divorce or lose my job because of that. But still. I was shocked to see that happening to my account. Questions going from one profile to the other out-of-the-blue.

Comment: Got your email - this was definitely an automated merge. You independently confirmed your email on one account and then logged in *using* that email on another account. I'll do my best to clean this up, but no guarantees.

Comment: Shog -  to make sure: I seem to be able to set any E-Mail address in my profile without confirmation. Would my setting it to `skeet@pobox.com` make it susceptible to an automatic merge with Jon's account? I'm assuming the answer is no and that automatic merges happen only with authenticated E-Mail addresses from OpenID providers, but the OP claimed at one point that he changed the *profile* E-Mail address, not the OpenID one

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks! If the email already exists it complains. Not sure how it happened to me. Maybe the email was already there before they started validating the uniqueness of the email? Also I can't be sure If they linked the two accounts by email or by something else.

Comment: @Pekka: although it's not entirely obvious, you can *confirm* your email address by opting in to various email-based functions on the site: inbox notifications and tag subscriptions both generate confirmation emails, I believe. Once that's done, the system "trusts" your address (until you change it of course).

Comment: @Astonished: I've mostly separated your accounts, and removed your email. You're correct that you can't add one account's email to another account, however you *can* log into one account with the email associated with another - if that email has been confirmed, the accounts may be merged. So far as I can tell, that's what happened here.

Comment: @Shog9 You are the man! :)

Comment: I think having more than one account should be against the TOS, like most other sites out there.

Comment: @Seth: if you use two accounts to *do* anything you couldn't do with a single account, that is a ToS violation and will result in one or more accounts being merged or deleted. If you don't... Meh.

Comment: Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bigger issue than "not supporting" different accounts with a verified email address in common. It's not that some feature failed to work, it's that the accounts were merged.

Of course accounts must never be automatically merged without explicit prompting and re-verification of all email addresses.

- **Wrongthink:** Someone posting on for example, Islam, or Judaism, or Christianity, or Politics may not want that account associated with their main account because it may harm their careers if bigots at their workplace become aware of their wrongthink.
- **Work email addresses**  Email addresses don't necessarily belong to the same person for life. Often at work leavers' email addresses are redirected to a team member or shared mailbox: That's my practice when I've been in charge of that.

  Should Clever Bob's replacement Stupid Joe be able to take over his 10k reputation just because Clever Bob used a work email address as an alternate login? Maybe you think Clever Bob must not be so clever, but was it really made clear to Clever Bob that this was a possibility?
- **Old or obsolete addresses:** Alternatively some freemail providers will re-issue email addresses which have not been logged into for a period of time. Unless you are affirmatively checking that the email is live every few months, you have no reason to assume it hasn't been reissued.