# I changed my email in my "Email Settings", and I'm not completely sure what happened

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, email

On my "DUO" account, I changed my email address in "Email settings" to my email address for my "Quote Dave" account. However, when I pressed "save", it changed my profile picture and name to those in my "Quote Dave" account. My questions are still the same, so I'm not completely sure what happened.

EDIT:
Great, now I can't sign into the "Winter Bash 2020" site :(

Comment: You have triggered an account merge. You can't have two accounts with the same email.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170073/275243).

Comment: @Kevin Ah, must have missed that. Well, I'm going to close it as "duplicate", then.

Comment: Why did you do it? What was your goal?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Honestly, it was an experiment to see what would happen.